# Terraform pass string as list using for expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create three elasticache redis users using a randomly generated password. These ES Redis users each will have a different name hence i am using `for_each` to set the username based on a `service_name`. This works great! The issue I am running is using a random password for that user. I am using the random password generator with a count of `3` one for each user. I am not able to pass the password as a list and running into this error: `Inappropriate value for attribute "passwords": set of string required.` Any help will be appreciated.

```
resource "random_password" "my_passwords" {
  count = 3
  length           = 19
  special          = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

resource "aws_elasticache_user" "my-users" {
  for_each = toset(var.my_service_names)
  user_id       = "${each.key}-${var.env}"
  user_name     = "${each.key}-${var.env}"
  access_string = "on ~* +@all"
  engine        = "REDIS"
  passwords     = "[for r random_password.my_passwords : r.result]"
```

Comment: You have a typo in your value for the `passwords` argument. You are casting your `for` expression inside the `list` constructor as a literal string because of your typo with the `"`. Remove the typo `"` from the value and let us know what occurs next.

Comment: I fixed that - still the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding the amount with a count on `random_password` I will use the same for loop...

See code below:

```
resource "random_password" "pws" {
  for_each         = toset(var.my_service_names)
  length           = 19
  special          = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}

resource "aws_elasticache_user" "my-users" {
  for_each      = toset(var.my_service_names)
  user_id       = "${each.key}-${var.env}"
  user_name     = "${each.key}-${var.env}"
  access_string = "on ~* +@all"
  engine        = "REDIS"
  passwords     = [ random_password.pws[each.key].result ]
}
```

That way the keys are the same on both resources, and we can access them from any resource that loops on the `my_service_names` just like I did there:
`random_password.pws[each.key].result`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Doug glad it worked for you, terraform is quite rigid, but once you done a few of these it becomes second nature